# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am not so long in flutter.I have `get` method. i have error `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

```
    Future<List<FineResponse>> getAll(String apiToken) async {
        try {
          Response response = await _dio.get(apiEndpoint + "fines",
            options: Options(
                headers: {
                  "Authorization": apiToken
                }),
          );
     
         return response.data
              .map<UserResponse>((el) => UserResponse.fromJson(el)).toList();
    
    
        } catch (error, stacktrace) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

expected response,i did in postman

```
    [
        [
            {
                "id": 1709,
                "uin": "188101772006228217193",
                "user_id": 1215,
       
            },
            {
                "id": 1710,
                "uin": "188101772006228217194",
                "user_id": 1215,
              
            },
            {
                "id": 1711,
                "uin": "1234567890123456789052",
                "user_id": 1215,
             
            },
            {
                "id": 1712,
                "uin": "1234567890123456789053",
                "user_id": 1215,
                
            }
        ]
    ]
```

```
    class FineResponse {
      int id;
      String uin;
      int userId;
      String comment;
      String addCoin;
      int statusId;
      int type;
      String createdAt;
      String updatedAt;
    
      FineResponse(
          {this.id,
            this.uin,
            this.userId,
            this.comment,
            this.addCoin,
            this.statusId,
            this.type,
            this.createdAt,
            this.updatedAt});
    
      FineResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        uin = json['uin'];
        userId = json['user_id'];
        comment = json['comment'];
        addCoin = json['add_coin'];
        statusId = json['status_id'];
        type = json['type'];
        createdAt = json['created_at'];
        updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['uin'] = this.uin;
        data['user_id'] = this.userId;
        data['comment'] = this.comment;
        data['add_coin'] = this.addCoin;
        data['status_id'] = this.statusId;
        data['type'] = this.type;
        data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
        data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

what should i change in my get method?

Comment: Can you print what `response.data` returns if you run your code?

Comment: [[{id: 1709, uin: 188101772006228217193, user_id: 1215, comment: null, add_coin: 2021-03-20 17:18, status_id: 5, type: 2, created_at: 2021-03-19 17:18:42, updated_at: 2021-03-19 17:18:42}, {id: 1711, uin: 1234567890123456789052, user_id: 1215, comment: null, add_coin: 2021-03-20 17:26, status_id: 5, type: 2, created_at: 2021-03-19 17:26:04, updated_at: 2021-03-19 17:26:04}]]

Comment: So you actually have a `List<List<Map<String,dynamic>>`?

Comment: yes i have List<List<Map<String,dynamic>>

Comment: Can you add your `UserResponse` class?

Comment: i edded UserResponse class

Comment: Why does your response returns a List of List?

Comment: beacuse backend dev did this)

Answer (score 0):

Since your `response.data` returns a `List<List<Map<String,dynamic>>` you need to create a `List<List<FineResponse>>` if you want the same output like in **Postman**.

```
final List<List<FineResponse>> fineResponses = 
    response.data.map((firstList) => 
        firstList.map((data) => 
            FineResponse.fromJson(data)
        ).toList()
    ).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a valid JSON response.

Please check your response here
[Check JSON response](https://jsonformatter.org/)

Comment: Yep it is invalid due to trailing comma